# python subprocess login to host create folder and exit from the host

Tags: ssh, remote-access, mkdir

I want to ssh to the host xyz.abc.pqr.com and make a directory "logs" and logout from the host.

```
like:
home$ ssh xyz.abc.pqr.com
xyz.abc.pqr.com $ mkdir logs
xyz.abc.pqr.com $ logout 
home$
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: What has this got to do with Python and subprocess?

Comment: i'm writting python code with subprocess module to workout the process.

Comment: @DeepakPorwal if you're ok with my answer, please consider upvoting it, else tell me what is wrong or missing.

Answer (score 0):

if a command is specified, ssh will execute i t and then close the connection:

```
 ssh user@xyz.abc.pqr.com "mkdir logs"
```

Comment: how to close the connection or logout to that server?